# How to switch between the classes, in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a game template which has two classes as its levels. 
The game has a player, enemies, treasure chests, and walls.
When I run the program, it loads Level 1, successfully. I have designed the code so if a certain condition is met, Level 2 must load. Now, Level 2 loads. But certain elements from Level 1 remain on screen, ignoring certain elements from Level 2.
To be exact:
From Level 2, it loads the player's initial coordinates, the treasure chests, and the final destination, ignoring the enemies and the walls.
It brings with itself from Level 1 to Level 2: the walls, the treasure chests, and the enemies. The latter two are in a frozen state. They don't function.

//Instance variables:

```
private int lvlCount = 1;
```

// Game() method

```
public Game(Stage stage) {
    this.score = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    this.mobs = new ArrayList<>();
    this.hitBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    this.treasure = new ArrayList<>(); 
    this.newLevel = new ArrayList<>();  
    this.enemyCount = 0;
    bg();
    loadLevel(1); 
    living();
    stuff();
    mob2();
    finalText();
    stage.setOnShown(e -> this.run());
}
```

//The switch for loading the Levels:

```
void loadLevel(int in) {
    switch (in) {
    case 1:
        this.level = new Level1();
        break;
    case 2:
        this.level = new Level2(); // placeholder for second level
        break;
    }
    hitBoxes.clear(); // clear the list of hitboxes
    mobs.clear(); // remove any existing old mobs
    this.getChildren().addAll(hitBoxes); // add all the hitboxes for the walls to the scene
    background.setImage(level.getImage()); // get the background image
    hitBoxes.addAll(level.getWalls()); // get all the wall hitboxes
    enemyCount = level.getEnemyCount(); // get the enemy count from the level
    chestCount = level.treasureCount(); // get the treasure count from the level
    this.initTreasure(chestCount); // add the treasure chests for the level
    this.initMobs(enemyCount); // initialize our mobs

    lvlCount = level.lvlCount();
    this.initLevel(lvlCount);


    }
```

//The collision check:

```
private void collisionCheck() {if (r.getFill().equals(Color.WHITE)){lvlCount--;}
```

//Main Game loop method:

```
private void play() {
    AnimationTimer gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {
public void handle(long arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mobs.size(); i++) {
                MOB m = mobs.get(i);
                if (m instanceof Enemy) {
                    ((Enemy) m).moveCheck(arg0);
                }
            }
 collisionCheck();
if (lvlCount == 0){
                loadLevel(2);} //The condition that loads Level 2
gameLoop.start();
}
```

Please help me to figure out how I can load Level 2, successfully.
Please note that it does not produce any errors in the console. So, I am having a very hard time figuring out where the problem lies.

I only pasted the code that I thought is necessary to achieve my goal. Here you can see the full code, for veiwing purposes only, no download necessary:
[http://paste.mooc.fi/955c6d30](https://paste.mooc.fi/955c6d30)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I fail to see the "full picture" here. There doesn't seem to be a call to `collisionCheck` which seems to be the only thing modifying `lvlCount`. Also all that a call to `loadLevel` only seems to be replacing a field which by itself has no effect on the scene whatsoever. Furthermore `gameLoop.start` for some reason seems to be called from the `handle` method of the same object...

Comment: As far as loadLevel() goes, it perfectly loads some of the components of Level 2. If it can load some, why doesn't it load all of them?

Comment: The full code has collisionCheck() in play(). gameLoop.start() is part of the template. Here is the full code:
https://www70.zippyshare.com/v/6uDa0nTT/file.html

Comment: "I only pasted the code" this is fine, but the posted code should reproduce the problem, so it should include creating / changing of walls , enemies etc. See [mcve].

Comment: @c0der updated void loadLevel(int in).
And also, here is the full code, no download necessary: http://paste.mooc.fi/955c6d30

Comment: Please do not link code but prepare an MCVE and post it. The linked code is not an MCVE. Please read [mcve] and ask if clarifications are needed. I find MCVE a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem. To get to know SO conventions better you may find  [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helpful.